# Blender sculpt is sculpting in the opposite direction and has static on it

Tags: mesh, sculpting

So I started this scuplt a bit ago and I think I had used seperate parts for the calf and lower leg and combind them but now coming back I see that after I had filled in the indent left by combinding those two (I think I just merged them idrk) it left this weird static and tells me it has an uniform scale. I went and tried everything here [sculpt tools act in incorrect direction](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16560/sculpt-tools-act-in-incorrect-direction) but I still have issues. First this did for a sec make it so my sculpt tools werent inverted, before if   I had my sculpt tool on the subtraction sign it would add and vice versa. But that only fixed it for a little bit. Im still very new to blender and these forums so I hope this is an okay discription.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello maybe check if the normals are not inverted? In Edit mode select all and press Shift N?

Comment: That didnt seem to work but thank you for the suggestion

Comment: Could you please share your file (remove some parts if you prefer not to share the whole thing)? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: It seems like its too big but ill try and remove a few things to see if it will let me!

Comment: was able to add it! I had to use the decimate modifier alot bc I had way too many faces on some of my objects

Comment: @moonboots im so sorry to ping you but I still have one of my problems and ive figured out what the problem is just not how to fix it! So I think when i first made the legs in joined them instead of using booleans so now i have a ton of intersecting faces

Comment: Not sure what you mean, if you have intersecting faces you could remesh in Sculpt mode?

Comment: I dont really know how to do that im sorry um ill add in a picture of the faces

Comment: In Sculpt mode press R to choose the size you want for the faces, then Ctrl R to remesh, it will remesh your mesh and should remove all intersecting faces

Answer (score 1):

The scale on X is negative, apply the scale in *Object* mode (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>):

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!!!